# Magento multistore - translating ALT tags and images & store view levels

Tags: multistore, localisation

Whilst translating a site to language 2 coming from language 1. We Changed the image ALT text (as seen in screenshot) thinking that Magento would: 
* use the image (+filename) from the default config or store name 
* but set the ALT and TITLE tag to the text we entered as the label value

Now I see that these ALT and TITLE tags are still set in language 1. Is this the correct way of working? It does not have a tickbox for "Use default value" - ...

**Question:** How can we easily set the ALT and TITLE tags per store view? (whilst not wanting to heave the whole image management to the store view. We kind of like it that the main image etc. are all set on store name level.)

So to sum up: our wish would be to respect the "Use default value" for Base,Small and Thumbnail image except for the Label value per store view

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Its easy - simply deselect the "Use Default" checkbox.
Magento will then use the default image with the store view label, just as you want.

Comment: Deselect which one? Base image

Comment: Whichever one you want the store view alt label to be used with. You can deselect only one or all three if you want.

Comment: I think the label should be used from store view. The checks are for overriding the image itself. So if we add a new image on def config then the store view should follow that. If we uncheck use default then the connection is lost.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you are out of luck. Probably easiest to add new attributes (image_label_custom, small_image_label_custom and thumbnail_label_custom) and then modify the template to use those instead the default labels as alt tags. The alternative would be a messa rewrite, which I would not recommend.

Comment: I'll have a look. What boggled me is that the name column has no own check mark. And can be edit and changed. But then it is not used? So my conclusion is that it exists in the database. I mean the backend can find it. Why not the front end.

Comment: I can't tell you "why", but they implemented the media gallery as a kind of "extended attribute value". The values are not stored as a regular EAV attribute value, but in a seperate table. For the frontend display the EAV attribute backend model simply sets the value on the entity, and they are rendered as if they where regular attributes. This architecture makes it less easy to change the scoping.