# Product images title translation

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, localisation

In product view the more images titles are coming in admin value of the option label, I have 6 store views and how can I make the title of the more images to show the specific store view value of the label rather than the admin value?

```
title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>"
```

I have tried `$_image->getStoreLabel()`  and `$_image->getFrontendLabel()` but it didn't worked.

Comment: Not reproducible in Magento 1.9 without extensions. Which Magento version are you using? Any product specific extensions? If the `media_gallery` attribute has been loaded correctly, `$_image->getLabel()` will return the localized value.

Comment: Or maybe this is actually a duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44451/magento-multistore-translating-alt-tags-and-images-store-view-levels and you did not uncheck the "use default" checkbox.